# How can I determine incoming messages coming per second in my Event hub?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am getting throttled request in my event hub at the time of ingress with 1 TU and auto inflate is disabled. How Can I determine incoming messages per second to figure out the required throughput units?

I checked Event hub metrics but didn't find metrics for same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you check the metrics? Actually you can check the `incoming messages per minute` in the `azure event hub`(or `event hub namespace`)metrics. Then you can determine the `incoming messages per second` based on that.

**1**.If you want to check the incoming messages for `event hub namespace`, follow the steps below:

Nav to azure portal -> the `event hub namespace` -> Overview page -> under "Show metrics", select "Messages" -> at last, mouse over on the graph, you can see "incoming messages per minutes". For the details, you can refer to the screenshot as below:

[image]

**2**.If you want to check incoming messages for each `event hub instance`, the almost same steps like mentioned above. See the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: thanks for such descriptive answer but i am interested for incoming messages per second.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal, ok. But later, if you cannot find a solution for that, as a workaround, you can get the avg of `incoming messages per second` as per this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get metrics about Event Hubs (an Event Hub is a Service Bus Entity) using the [Service Bus Entity Metrics REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported?redirectedfrom=MSDN#microsoftservicebusnamespaces) and he is a video [about it](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Subscribe/Service-Bus-Namespace-Management-and-Analytics)

Comment: what do you mean by not working? write down the issue you are facing

Comment: I am not getting SASToken for API- POST https://your-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/your-event-hub/messages?timeout=60&api-version=2014-01 HTTP/1.1